# consider i inside a for loop as a vector and not as a character in R

Tags: r, match, quote

I have several vectors named: aa, bb, ab, ac, etc.
I'd like to use their names ("01","02","03","04", etc) to match the vectors with a df.
But I get an error because `names(i)`  doesn't work, given that (in case i <- "aa") R reads `names("aa")`, instead of: `names(aa)`.
How can be solved?

`noquote(i)` worked, but not inside names: `names(noquote(i))`. This produced an error.

```
x <- c("aa","bb","ab","ac")
names(x) <- c("01","02","03","04")

for (i in x) {
  df[match(names(i), df$ID), i] <- noquote(i)
}
```

########################################

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("01","02","02","03","03","03"), 
                 var_1 = c(0,0,1,0,0,1),
                 var_2 = c(0,0,0,0,1,0),
                 var_3 = c(1,0,0,0,0,0))

aa <- tapply(df$var_1, df$ID, max, na.rm = T)
bb <- tapply(df$var_2, df$ID, max, na.rm = T)
cc <- tapply(df$var_3, df$ID, max, na.rm = T)
```

In df_2 there's just one rown for each ID and I want to include in df_2 the vectors I created with tapply.

```
df_2 <- data.frame(ID=c("01","02","03"), age=c(34,12,49))
```

In order to match exactly the ID I used the following code:

```
df_2[match(names(aa), df_2$ID), "aa"] <- aa
df_2[match(names(bb), df_2$ID), "bb"] <- bb
df_2[match(names(cc), df_2$ID), "cc"] <- cc
```

In order to avoid this repetition of code I was trying to use this code (that i wrote at the beginning of the post):

```
x <- c("aa","bb","cc")
    
    for (i in x) {
      df_2[match(names(i), df_2$ID), i] <- noquote(i)
    }
```

but I have a problem with `names(i)`

Comment: I have a feeling the solution is simple, but can't be sure without a reproducible example of the `df`. Could you provide that to maximize chances of getting an answer?

Comment: What are you trying to define with: names(x) <- c("01","02","03","04")? Can you please try to clarify the question?

Comment: You should [use a list of data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207). (Or lists in general)

Comment: If you make your example fully reproducible (share sample `aa`, `bb` vectors and a small sample `df`), I'd be happy to demonstrate.

Comment: I added my post with an example

Comment: I find the logic still very confusing. What is your desired output? A df called `df_2` that has the information on `aa`, `bb` and `cc`?

Comment: Yes, it is right. Unfortunately with just a small example it seems not logic.

Comment: I edited my post because there was a mistake

Comment: `names` will get you only the names iof `x`, not the names of the items extracted by `in`. If you wnat to index with numers use `for( i in seq_along(x)){.}` and work with `x[i]` or `names(x)[i]` in your code. And if you have a character vector , say `char="aa"` and need to pull in values from the symbol table of your workspace, then use `get(char)` which will return the value of the data object named `aa`.

Comment: Like the other commenters here, I can't figure out what you're trying to achieve. I would recommend providing your expected output.